# Loading state via ChangeNotifierProvider is not showing

Tags: flutter, dart

This is my code. I want to show `CircularprogressIndicator` when tapped the `SpeedDialChild`. So I made `ChangeNotifier` as below. And show `CircularprogressIndicator` as stack using `Consumer`. But `Consumer` doesn't upadate my ui. How can solve this problem?

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<loading>(
      create: (_) => loading(),
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
          children: [
            Container(
              child: GoogleMap(
                initialCameraPosition: _currentlo,
              ),
            ),
            Consumer<loading>(
              builder: (context, value, child) => value.getloading() ?
              Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()) : Container(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        floatingActionButton: Builder(
          builder: (BuildContext context){
            return SpeedDial(
              children: [
                SpeedDialChild(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                    child: Icon(Icons.refresh, color: Colors.black,),
                    onTap: (){
                      Provider.of<loading>(context, listen: false).yesloading();
                      refreshMarkers();
                      Provider.of<loading>(context, listen: false).noloading();
                    }
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

class loading with ChangeNotifier{
  bool _isloading = false;

  bool getloading(){
    return _isloading;
  }

  void yesloading(){
    _isloading = true;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void noloading(){
    _isloading = false;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you set your loading variable to false again immediately (synchronously):

```dart
Provider.of<loading>(context, listen: false).noloading();
```

If you remove this line, your loading indicator will be displayed.

You probably want to `await` your `refreshMarkers` call instead. If `refreshMarkers` returns a `Future`, you should be able to do that:

```dart
onTap: () async {
  Provider.of<loading>(context, listen: false).yesloading();
  await refreshMarkers();
  Provider.of<loading>(context, listen: false).noloading();
}
```

Now, you will see your loading indicator while `refreshMarkers` is completing.

---

[Learn about asynchronous programming in Dart](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await).
Furthermore, you can and probably should take a look at the [Effective Dart: Style](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/style) guide in order to make your code readable.